# AngularJS - How to expose service properties

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am having a hard time exposing properties from an Angular service. In the example below, I am exposing two properties in `authService`: `isAuthenticated` and `user`. However when `isAuthenticated` changes, it is not picked up by the `HomeController`. Can someone help me understand where I am going wrong?

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Define the 'app' module
    angular.module('app', []);

    // Use the 'app' module
    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('LoginController', LoginController)
        .controller('HomeController', HomeController)
        .factory('authService', authService);


    // ----- LoginController -----
    LoginController.$inject = ['authService'];
    function LoginController(authService) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.username = null;
        vm.password = null;
        vm.login = login;

        function login() {
            authService.login(vm.username, vm.password);
        }
    }


    // ----- HomeController -----
    HomeController.$inject = ['$scope', 'authService'];
    function HomeController($scope, authService) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.user = null;

        $scope.$watch(
            function() { return authService.isAuthenticated; },
            function() {
                console.log('HomeController: isAuthenticated changed');
                vm.user = authService.user;
            }
        );
    }


    // ----- authService -----
    function authService() {

        var isAuthenticated = false;
        var user = { username: 'jdoe', location: 'Dreamland' };

        var service = {
            login: login,
            isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated,
            user: user
        };

        return service;

        function login(username, password) {

            user = {
                username: username,
                location: 'Boston'
            };

            isAuthenticated = true;
            console.log('authService: isAuthenticated changed');
        }
    }

})();
```

Here's the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app" ng-strict-di>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularJS Minimal Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="LoginController as vm">
        <form name="loginForm" ng-submit="vm.login()">
            <label>Username: </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="vm.username">

            <label>Password: </label>
            <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="vm.password">

            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="HomeController as vm">
        <h1>{{vm.user.username}}</h1>
        <h2>{{vm.user.location}}</h2>
    </div>

    <!-- JavaScript at the bottom for fast page loading -->
    <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: service.isAuthenticated = true, instead of that. boolean is pass by value, not reference.

Comment: Rather than making isAuthenticated a local variable I would just have isAuthenticated: false when you initialize the service object. Then in your login function you can set service.isAuthenicated to true and return that singleton object in your service. In JS functions are hoisted to the top which means that the var isAuthenticated = false comes after the login function when your code is interpreted. This could be causing your problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do this:

```
var service = {
    login: login,
    isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated,
    user: user
};
```

You're creating copies of `login`, `isAuthenticated`, and `user` (although `user` is a reference to the same object).

Then, when you do this:

```
function login(username, password) {

    user = {
        username: username,
        location: 'Boston'
    };

    isAuthenticated = true;
    console.log('authService: isAuthenticated changed');
}
```

You are reassigning the *local* `user` variable to a new object and the *local* `isAuthenticated` variable to `true`. Your `service` object still refers to the *old* values of these variables.

The most straight forward way to fix this is to assign directly to your service variables:

```
function login(username, password) {

    service.user = {
        username: username,
        location: 'Boston'
    };

    service.isAuthenticated = true;
    console.log('authService: isAuthenticated changed');
}
```

This way, the service variables will be updated, and should be reflected anywhere that the service is used. In this scenario, you don't need the local variables anymore - the service object already houses them. Use local variables for private, unexposed variables.

Comment: _"You're creating copies of login, isAuthenticated, and user"_ - Not really. These are only assignments. You can't copy `false`.

Comment: @zeroflagL Yup. All I mean is that, for example, `service.isAuthenticated` becomes a copy of `isAuthenticated` - although both are identical to `false`, `service.isAuthenticated` is a copy of `isAuthenticated` because `isAuthenticated` can be changed without affecting `service.isAuthenticated`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this

```
var service = {
            login: login,
            isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated,
            user: user
        };
```

Try doing this

```
var service = {
            login: login,
            isAuthenticated: function() { return isAuthenticated; },
            user: function() { return user; }
        };
```

Then you need to call it as a function not as a value. That will check `isAuthenticated` value and return it everytime you call `service.isAuthenticated()`. You should do the same with `user`. You should call `service.user()`.

Comment: Thanks, @Mindastic. This fixes one issue. The $watch is now working and is called whenever `isAuthenticated` changes. However, `authService.user` does not pickup the new value of the user. It still has the initial value (jdoe/Dreamland). I tried changing var service to `user: function() { return user; }`, but that does not help.

Comment: For the user, you should do pretty much the same. Check my updated answer.

Comment: That unfortunately does not work. I had edited my earlier comment to say that, probably you did not read the edited version. Anyway, see @Agop's answer, that works.